# Laravel 4 using php to create dynamic blade commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this blade view template

```
<title><?
$page = App::make('page');
echo $page->getTitle( );
?></title>
<?php 
$css = $page->getCssList('all');

foreach($css as $item){?>
    {{ HTML::style('<?=$item['loc'];?>', array('media' => '<?=$item['media'];?>'))}}    
<?}

$js = $page->getJsList('all');
foreach($js as $item){?>
    {{ HTML::script('<?=$item['loc'];?>')}} 
<?}?>
```

It does not work. What happens is it actually outputs the blade commands to the screen.
If i cut and paste these blade command into the view then they are rendered correctly.

What is the problem? Is is not possible to create dynamic blade commands? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use a normal `view` instead of `Blade` so it will work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm only new to laravel. How do you run it as view and not blade? This is called via $this->layout->content = View::make('users.register'); which create the content for the main page view that that above code is included in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PHP inside of PHP.

Change this

```
{{ HTML::script('<?=$item['loc'];?>')}}
```

to this

```
{{ HTML::script($item['loc']) }}
```

and change

```
{{ HTML::style('<?=$item['loc'];?>', array('media' => '<?=$item['media'];?>'))}}
```

to

```
{{ HTML::style($item['loc'], array('media' => $item['media'])) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces are simply a shortcut for printing PHP code.

You can just write

```
{{ HTML::script($item['loc']) }}
```

Which is functionally identical to

```
<?php echo HTML::script($item['loc']); ?>
```